# Combine images in Python

Tags: python

I have around 2000 folders with four images each folder and I would like to combine the images from each folder. the problem that I face is that I can not give the right path/directory in order to read the folder with the images
I would like to use this code:

```py
import sys
from PIL import Image
import os
from os.path import join as jn
import pandas as pd

files = "C:/Users/..."
os.listdir(files)

images = [Image.open(x) for x in ['gsv_0.jpg', 'gsv_1.jpg', 'gsv_2.jpg', 'gsv_3.jpg']]
widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))

total_width = sum(widths)
max_height = max(heights)

new_im = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, max_height))

x_offset = 0
for im in images:
  new_im.paste(im, (x_offset,0))
  x_offset += im.size[0]

new_im.save('image1.jpg')"
```

I am getting the error below

---

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 images = [Image.open(x) for x in ['gsv_0.jpg', 'gsv_1.jpg', 'gsv_2.jpg', 'gsv_3.jpg']]
      2 widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))
      3 
      4 total_width = sum(widths)
      5 max_height = max(heights)

in (.0)
----> 1 images = [Image.open(x) for x in ['gsv_0.jpg', 'gsv_1.jpg', 'gsv_2.jpg', 'gsv_3.jpg']]
      2 widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))
      3 
      4 total_width = sum(widths)
      5 max_height = max(heights)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2632 
   2633     if filename:
-> 2634         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
   2635         exclusive_fp = True
   2636

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gsv_0.jpg'

Comment: `files = "C:/Users/..." os.listdir(files)`, this will throw an error as the system cannot find the path specified. But, anyway, if there are 2k folders, then `Image.open(x)` should follow a path right until x right?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues you can be coming across.

1. If you are running the script via the command line then you need to have the images in the same directory as the script that runs this file.  This may differ if you are calling this script from another class though.
2. If you are using PyCharm I know that in the past I had issues with where files needed to be located because you need to add the files into a specific folder via imports through their menu. -> if this is the case I would search "where to place input files in pycharm"

Hope this helps

Comment: I should note that it looks like you are grabbing a list of Directories but you are just listing the...  not actually using them in the loop.